# My conceal options are not loading in vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have some conceal options (`syntax match Normal '\.md\]' conceal cchar=]`) added in a `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/base.vim`.

They are not loaded when I open a file. But if i do `:source $HOME/.vim/after/syntax/base.vim` the conceal is activated.

In `.vimrc` I have also this:

```
syntax on
set conceallevel=2
```

I even tried with this options in my `.vimrc`

```
source ~/.vim/after/syntax/base.vim
let g:mysyntaxfile = '~/.vim/after/syntax/base.vim'
au VimEnter,BufEnter source ~/.vim/after/syntax/base.vim
```

Nothing works. Only source from vim Command Mode.

Answer (score 0):

`base.vim` should have been `markdown.vim`. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

When they are not sourced explicitly, with something like `source /path/to/foo.vim` or `runtime foo.vim`, syntax scripts are sourced automatically on a per-filetype basis. Basically…

1. `:e foo.js` creates a buffer for that file,
2. Vim picks up that it is a JavaScript file so it assigns the `javascript` filetype and the `javascript` syntax,
3. Vim sources all the `*/syntax/javascript.vim` scripts it can find in `$RUNTIMEPATH`.

Conclusion: if you want to source a specific syntax script for a specific filetype, name it appropriately:

```
<filetype>.vim
```